# Having a big list of static data into code instead of a database?

Tags: .net, database, design-patterns, architecture

We currently have one app that has a somewhat big database with only static data (readonly).

We are considering to deploy the data in the form of compiled assembly with model objects constructed filling collections. A quick example:

```
public Model()
{
    this.Property1 = new List<AClass>();
    this.Property1.Add(new AClass(1,2));
    this.Property1.Add(new AClass(4,3));
    this.Property1.Add(new AClass(2,6));
}
```

The main concern the people has is that they never saw someone doing it this way. Have you seen / used this approach before?

The main benefits are that you don't need anymore a data access layer and you have faster performance.

EDIT: The readonly database is currently generated by a tool so the code would be generated by a tool as well.

Comment: Is .Net, sorry. But probably the language does not matter in this case.

Comment: Well, it does. If .net has enums, then I would use that

Comment: Enums cannot have objects, just values. We would store the whole datamodel on code.

Comment: Are you sure? In java enums can have pretty much anything

Comment: Yes I am. Just checked what you said and you're right. Anyway you would find it ok to have enums with some hundreds of objects in code ok?

Comment: (In java) the enum would be the *collection* of entries - each instance of the enum would be (like) a `AClass(1,2)`, or *have* a `AClass`, or *be* a `AClass` if `AClass` were an interface

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32958/discussion-between-somos-and-bohemian)

Comment: @OP I still don't understand why you must do it this way. If a database is out of the question, have you considered an xml file? If you use xml, you could save the data there and easily serialize it into the objects that you need.

Comment: @OP You might also want to look at some of the WinRT classes that are suggested by Microsoft to be used on windows tablet querying. Since a database isn't deployed with windows 8 apps (for obvious reasons), there are WinRT classes provided by microsoft that allow you to query an xml data file much like a database. Since this is the preferred approach from Microsoft for apps that run on small tablets, I doubt performance would be much of an issue.

Comment: The question is: why do we need a database or some files to store static data?

Comment: I see no problem with your approach.  If you tool will create the correct syntax then go for it.  Why read from an XML file?  Why chance users hacking into the XML file?

Comment: Do you perform joins and complex queries against your database?  Or do you mostly perform keyed lookups?

Answer (score 1):

I've embedded data that would otherwise be in a database inside of an application many times. No XML file, no plain text file, no database.

I usually only do that for small amounts of data that I think will never change.

The reason for that is always laziness. I don't want to make a database, a schema, write the data access code, etc. In those cases even making an XML file is too much work for small amounts of data.

If all the data is read only, I think it's a fun idea to deploy assemblies instead of an actual database. As you said it removes a very and potentially problematic dependency.

The only downside I can think of is that when you're doing queries, the assembly potentially has to load a very large amount of data into memory. As long as you have some sort of lazy loading functionality, I think it would work great.

Answer (score 1):

Actually they are 2 different types of list:

1. Data Lists / Master Data

   This is a list where stored in database. Usually the list is large and having small impact into code logic. For example is Country / Nation, list of fonts, etc. This should be put at database. If there are impact to code logic (e.g if the nation is US, then show the Zip box), the configuration should be put at database (such as `IsShowZip`). This has no benefit if stored in application / assembly.
2. Application Lists

   This is a list where the impact to code logic is big. Usually it affects business process (workflow) significantly, or has specific database schema. For example, payment type Credit card / internet commerce such as Paypal. It will affect the workflow (if from paypal maybe need to wait for verification from there) and inputs (credit card number / paypal number). This has only one benefit if stored in database, as it can act as a constraint to input (so it won't be other value except `Paypal` / `Credit Card` in `Payment Type`). However, it depends on how your database access is, and it can create a hidden dependency between application and database.

UPDATE:

I missing the `readonly database` section. To make it clear, there are the cons and pros using `readonly database` refering to point no.1 above:

pros:

1. Can take advantage over indexing and query optimization. This apply to filtering data
2. If the database is centralized or using server-client architecture (maybe not applicable in this issue), you can modify the database without having changes to every client
3. Does not give code revision history for updating data.

cons:

1. Overhead when doing query to database (performance impact).
2. Additional avoidable dependency - (YAGNI - You Ain't Gonna Need it)

Comment: "This has no benefit if stored in application / assembly" <-- strongly disagree: it has the benefit or removing one application layer, simplifying the deployment as you need one file less, eases versioning as the data is inside the application. I can only find benefits removing the database from scenario 1.

Comment: May I get the real use case about what kind of app it is. Is it use database for transaction or not, or is it use local save as file for storage?

Comment: As I said in the question the data is absolutely readonly so no transactions at all, just reading the data.

Comment: Well, I misread the `readonly` database. This is the first time I see an application using database for read only. Absolutely it can remove the useless dependency, unless huge data (100k ++) is stored in the list, because no indexes and initialization.